# (Microsoft Dynamics Online) Get Account GUID inside embedded Web Resource

Tags: html, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to access entities (Contacts) in a HTML WebResource inside an Account formular in Microsoft Dynamics. However I cannot figure out how to get the record GUID (accountId) from the PageContext. It tells me the entityId is undefined.

I'm trying to replace this deprechated code line:

```
  const accountId = parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
```

I've been trying to use

```
const pageContext = window.parent.Xrm.Utility.getPageContext();
```

but the attributes are almost all null or undefined including the entityId. All it tells me is that I'm in an account record. See image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2aSA.jpg

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible, you were close in your second attempt.

This will return the id:

```
var id = parent.Xrm.Utility.getPageContext().input.entityId.replace("{", '').replace("}", '');
```

From Microsoft docs:
[Pass parameters to HTML web resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/webpage-html-web-resources?view=op-9-1#pass-parameters-to-html-web-resources)